# Position in JSON string to path in the object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON string similar to this one:

```
{
    "Version": "XXX",
    "Statements": [
        {...},
        {...},
        {...}
    ]
}
```

How can I find out which object inside Statements property is defined at character `XX` of the JSON string? (considering that those objects can have arbitrarily deep nesting).

For example, if I have a string

```
{"Version":"XXX","Statements":[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"b":3}]}
--------------------------------------------------------
123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456
```

then character at position `36` would correspond to the first statement object, while character at position `52` would correspond to the third statement object.

Comment: Please provide an example. I don’t know what string you’re talking about and what `X` could be, or how a character relates to positions of objects.

Comment: `indexOf`? Or am I oversimplifying the problem..

Comment: I've added an example. Thank you!

Comment: You're looking for a custom algorithm that will (1) make a lot of assumptions (2) take a lot of time to construct.  Not saying someone won't take on this challenge, but I find it too much of an endeavor for me for volunteer work.

Comment: @vol7ron I'm hoping that this has been solved before. I imagine any decent editor with autocomplete functionality will have to do this in a more generic way.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly youre trying to achieve?

Comment: This is a job for lexxing/parsing, which I doubt you will find anyone willing to write you one in a SO answer. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/16/hand-written-lexer-in-javascript-compared-to-the-regex-based-ones

Comment: @tommyO I have a JSON string in the textarea and need to intelligently make some changes to the object which which caret is positioned. So if cursor is within first statement, when customer clicks a button, I'll deserialize contents, modify object, serialize it again and update textarea. The problem I have is figuring out which statement object caret is in so I could modify it accordingly.

Comment: @ChadGrant I'm hoping there is a package or JS library that does it. With C# NewtonsoftJSON is able to do what I want (parse JSON while preserving line/character position of each token) but I couldnt find any purely JS-based solutions. Certainly writing one from scratch is a major undertaking and I'm not expecting that.

Comment: Do you need to handle the situation in which the carat is at a boundary between items, such as at the `,` in `[{"a":"a"},{"b":"b"}]` and select the enclosing array? Or do you only care about situations in which the carat is touching either a key or a value on at least one of its sides?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I would like to know that info, then I could just pick one to the left of the cursor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing a bunch of research, I think I have a way forward without writing my own parser by using `esprima` package. Since esprima it's not JSON specific (but rather JavaScript), I have to wrap my JSON string into brackets.

Each element in tree contains `loc` property with a range matching it to position in original JSON string.

```js
var esprima = require("esprima");
var JSONPath = require('JSONPath');

function getStatementIndex(str, line, column) {
 var tree = esprima.parseScript(str, {loc:true});
 var query = "$.body[0].expression.properties[?(@.key.value=='Statement')].value.elements[*].loc";
 var locations = JSONPath({json: tree, path: query});
 
 console.log(locations);
 
 for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  var loc = locations[i];
  
  var contains = false;
  
  if (loc.start.line < line && loc.end.line > line) {
   continue;
  }
  
  // If a single line and in between
  if (loc.start.line == loc.end.line && loc.start.line == line) {
   if (loc.start.column <= column && loc.end.column >= column) {
    contains = true;
   }
   
  // If on the beginning line
  } else if (loc.start.line == line && loc.start.column <= column) {
   contains = true;
  
  // If on the end line
  } else if (loc.end.line == line && loc.end.column >= column) {
   contains = true;
  
  // If in between
  } else if (loc.start.line < line  && loc.end.line > line) {
   contains = true;
  }
     
  if (contains)
   return i;
 }
 
 return -1;
}

var result = getStatementIndex(str, 81, 7);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is some dirty solution that doesn't require external libs:

```js
const data = '{"Version":"XXX","Statements":[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"b":3}],"some":0}';

const getValuesPositionInArray = arrayKey => data => {
  const arrayNameSeparator = `"${arrayKey}":`;
  const targetArrayIndexOf = data.indexOf(arrayNameSeparator) + arrayNameSeparator.length;
  const arrayStringWithRest = data.slice(targetArrayIndexOf, data.length);
  
  const { result } = arrayStringWithRest.split('').reduce(
    (acc, char, idx, array) => {
      if (acc.finished) return acc;
      if (!acc.processingKey && char === '[') acc.nesting += 1;
      if (!acc.processingKey && char === ']') acc.nesting -= 1;
      
      const shouldFinish = acc.nesting === 0;
      const charIsDblQuote = char === '"';
      const charBefore = array[idx - 1];
      const charAfter = array[idx + 1];
      
      acc.position += 1;
      acc.finished = shouldFinish;

      if (acc.processingKey && !charIsDblQuote) acc.processedKey += char;
      if (charIsDblQuote) acc.processingKey = !acc.processingKey;
      if (charIsDblQuote && !acc.processingKey && charAfter === ':') {
       acc.result[acc.processedKey] = acc.position;
        acc.processedKey = '';
      }
      
      return acc;
    }, 
    { 
      finished: false, 
      processingKey: false,
      processedKey: '',
      nesting: 0,
      position: targetArrayIndexOf + 1,
      result: {}
    }
  )
  
  return result;
  
}

const result = getValuesPositionInArray('Statements')(data);

console.log(result)
```

But this snippet will break if target objects would contain string values.

**EDIT**

And below is updated snippet with string values fix and with parsed values as well:

```js
const data = '{"Version":"XXX","Statements":[{"aa":"some"},{"b":"ano:,{ther}"},{"bb":3}],"some":0}';

const getValuesPositionInArray = arrayKey => data => {
  const arrayNameSeparator = `"${arrayKey}":`;
  const targetArrayIndexOf = data.indexOf(arrayNameSeparator) + arrayNameSeparator.length;
  const arrayStringWithRest = data.slice(targetArrayIndexOf, data.length);
  const charsAfterValue = ['}', ','];
  const charsBeforeKey = ['{', ','];

  const { result } = arrayStringWithRest.split('').reduce(
    (acc, char, idx, array) => {
      if (acc.finished) return acc;
      if (!acc.processingKey && !acc.processingValue && char === '[') acc.nesting += 1;
      if (!acc.processingKey && !acc.processingValue && char === ']') acc.nesting -= 1;

      const shouldFinish = acc.nesting === 0;
      const charIsDblQuote = char === '"';
      const charBefore = array[idx - 1];
      const charAfter = array[idx + 1];
     
      const keyProcessingStarted = (
        charIsDblQuote &&
        !acc.processingKey &&
        !acc.processingValue &&
        charsBeforeKey.includes(charBefore)
      );

      const keyProcessingFinished = (
        charAfter === ':' &&
        charIsDblQuote && 
        acc.processingKey 
      );

      const valueProcessingStarted = (
        char === ':' &&
        !acc.processingKey &&
        !acc.processingValue
      );

      const valueProcessingFinished = (
        (acc.lastProcessedValueType === String
          ? charIsDblQuote
          : true
        ) &&
        acc.processingValue &&
        charsAfterValue.includes(charAfter)
      );

      acc.position += 1;
      acc.finished = shouldFinish;

      if (acc.processingKey && !charIsDblQuote) acc.processedKey += char;
      if (acc.processingValue && !charIsDblQuote) acc.processedValue += char;
      
      if (keyProcessingStarted) {
        acc.processingKey = true;
      } else if (keyProcessingFinished) {
        acc.processingKey = false;
        acc.result[acc.processedKey] = { position: acc.position };
        acc.lastProcessedKey = acc.processedKey;
        acc.processedKey = '';
      }

      if (valueProcessingStarted) {
        acc.processingValue = true;
        acc.lastProcessedValueType = charAfter === '"' ? String : Number;
      } else if (valueProcessingFinished) {
        acc.processingValue = false;
       acc.result[acc.lastProcessedKey].value = (
          acc.lastProcessedValueType(acc.processedValue)
        );
        acc.processedValue = '';
        acc.lastProcessedKey = '';
        acc.lastProcessedValueType = (v) => v;
      }

      return acc;
    },
    {
      finished: false,
      processingKey: false,
      processingValue: false,
      processedKey: '',
      processedValue: '',
      lastProcessedKey: '',
      lastProcessedValueType: (v) => v,
      nesting: 0,
      position: targetArrayIndexOf + 1,
      result: {}
    }
  )

  return result;

}

const result = getValuesPositionInArray('Statements')(data);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

To find the position of something in the json string, if you want to build your own algorithm, there are several things to take into account, one issue is that several strings could lead to the same object literal, also the order of properties in the objects is not guaranteed, then same string could lead to *different order* in the properties. We know that every `.` means `{` in the string, but `[` could mean `[` or `{` . So to find the position of `1` for example, we should remove the spaces in the original string and perform recursive loops and build a json again and find the match.  Here just an example to find the position of **1**:

```js
var json = '{"Version":"XXX","Statements":[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"b":3}]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(json)

var str2 = ""

for(p in obj){
    str2 += "{";
    str2 += p+":";
    if(p == "Statements"){
        str2 += ":["
        obj[p].forEach(o=>{            
            for(p2 in o){
                if(p2 == "a"){
                    str2 += '{"a":'
                }
            }
        })
    }else{
        str2 +='"'+obj[p]+'",'
    }    
}
console.log(str2)
console.log(str2.length+1)
```

This example is not accurate, it's just to show you one possible approach. In a real and general solution you should take into account hundreds of things.

Comment: I'm essentially trying to map Object literals to their definition in JSON string.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you for providing this example. I guess this relies on JSON.parse preserving order of properties as they are in JSON. I'll need to verify that's how it works.